# Meteor MongoDB Error

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have this issue with my meteor app. When I run this query on my chrome console, It returns the expected data
    Questions.find({}, {sort:{commentLength: -1}})

but when I run it in the console as `db.questions.find({}, {sort:{commentLength: -1}})`

it returns this error

```
error: {
  "$err" : "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue Unsupported projection option: sort: { commentLength: -1.0 }",
  "code" : 17287
}
```

Why does this error happen? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/) has a different syntax when executed in a mongodb shell. Try this instead:

```
db.questions.find().sort({commentLength: -1})
```